# can't seem to get this function with bash to work

Tags: bash

```
# define some variables for later
date=`date`
usr=`whoami`

# define usage function to echo syntax if no args given
usage(){
    echo "error: filename not specified"
    echo "Usage: $0 filename directory/ directory/ directory/"
    exit 1
}

# define copyall function
copyall() {
    # local variable to take the first argument as file
    local file="$1" dir
    # shift to the next argument(s)
    shift

    # loop through the next argument(s) and copy $file to them
    for dir in "$@"; do
        cp -R "$file" "$dir"
    done
}

# function to check if filename exists
# $f -> store argument passed to the script
file_exists(){
    local f="$1"
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && return 0 || return 1
}
# call usage() function to print out syntax
[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && usage
```

here's what I can't figure out

```
# call file_exists() and copyall() to do the dirty work
if ( file_exists "$1" ) then
    copyall
```

I would also love to figure out how to take this next echo section and condense it to one line. Instead of $1 then shift then move on. Maybe split it into an array?

```
    echo "copyall: File $1 was copied to"
    shift 
    echo "$@ on $date by $usr"
else
    echo "Filename not found"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: You can drop the `&& return 0 || return 1`; having the last line of the function simply be `[[ -f "$f" ]]` will cause 0 to be returned if the file exists and 1 if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the `file_exists` macro is superfluous:

```
if [ -f "$1" ]
then copy_all "$@"
else echo "$0: no such file as $1" >&2; exit 1
fi
```

or even just:

```
[ -f "$1" ] && copy_all "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to remove the parentheses around `file_exists "$1"`, and add a semicolon:

```
if file_exists "$1"; then
    copyall
```

Comment: just fixed the formatting; perhaps it will be easier to read now. I also tried removing the ()'s and still no go.

Comment: it just echos file was copied but the copyall function isn't even called it seems. no errors or anything. even with an echo in the copyall function, that doesn't even display.

Comment: needed to be copyall "$@" and that fixed it.